# Asynchronous Computation in scalajs Diode

Tags: scala.js, diode

I have an user interface and provide a button to the user, which executes the function `longComputation(x: A): A` and updates then the user interface (particularly the model) with the new result. This function may take longer to compute the result and should therefore compute in parallel.

[Diode](https://github.com/suzaku-io/diode) provides me with `Effect`, `PotAction`, and `AsyncAction`. I read the documentation about [Effects](https://github.com/suzaku-io/diode/blob/master/doc/usage/Effects.md) and [PotActions/AsyncActions](https://github.com/suzaku-io/diode/blob/master/doc/advanced/Pot.md), but I cannot even get a simple example to work.

Can someone point me to or provide an simple working example?

I created a [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/VcsE5P4/0) based on the `SimpleCounter` example. There is a `LongComputation` button, which should run in parallel; but is not.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you cannot run things in parallel without using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) because the JS engine is single-threaded. Web Workers are more like separate processes than threads, as they don't share memory and you need to send messages to communicate between workers and the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Have less than 50 reputation to comment, so I have to create a new answer instead of commenting @ochrons answer:

As mentioned Web Workers communicate via message passing and share no state. This concept is somehow similar to Akka - even [Akka.js](https://github.com/akka-js/akka.js) exists which enables you to use actor systems in ScalaJS and therefore the browser.